# Filter data for a particular user in loopback application

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am using loopback framework for my node.js API. In that i want to filter the data for the logged in user..

I tried the following:

```
http://localhost:3100/api/model?userid=1

Model.beforeRemote("find",function(ctx, expenses, next){
        ctx.args.filter = ctx.req.query;
        next();
    });
```

But its not filtering.. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a background :- we are using loopback app for our node application, and successfully serving more than 8000 rpm,

To accomplish what you are asking, what you should do is,

1. step:1 setup a correct relation between the user and model. like

model should belong to user, and user hasMany model.

Suppose we are building a reviews model then the reviews will belong to user and a user may have many reviews so hasMany relationship.

```
"reviews": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
```

2. Now to get all the reviews for a particular user, you can use the below mentioned api end point.

/api/User/{user-id}/Reviews

Check the loopback explorer for the correct documentation.

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/BelongsTo+relations

Comment: :+1 yr loopback explorer, is very helpful in api's learning. please go through it once. and the relations